# BigCommerce Use API To Get Customer Email In iOS

Tags: ios, api, get, bigcommerce

I am working on expanding functionality on an existing app I made that displays content from a Big Commerce store.  Basically, I want the app to be able to check if the email address the user types in on the iPhone exists in the Customer list and then perform action based on this.  I have an API Key and Call method to get the Customer list, but am not sure how best to perform this action on iOS.  Can someone give me some pointers on what I need to do to call this?

UPDATE:  I have used the following code so far:

```
-(IBAction)gettingcustomers {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mystoreserver.customers.json"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:10];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

    NSError *requestError;
    NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;


    NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
    NSLog(@"%@", requestError);
}
```

The error in the log shows:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0xa7d12e0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=mystoreserver.customers.json, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=mystoreserver.customers.json, NSUnderlyingError=0xa7da430 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the error means kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication.

There are a few issues in your code:

1. Don't invoke a synchronous network request from the main thread (big bummer!) Since the network request may take several seconds up to a minute, it will block the main thread and thus the UI.
2. Don't set the timeout that short, if you want that your app works with a cellular connection. The default is OK. Even better, set it very high an let the user cancel it (which requires to use `NSURLConnection` in asynchronous mode).
3. *Properly* check for errors. Basically, methods that have a pointer to a `NSError` object pointer as last parameter indicate success or failure with its *return value*. That is, in order to figure out whether there was an error or not *check the return value only*! If and only if the return value indicates an error, the error parameter may point to a meaningful `NSError` object.
4. The reason why the request fails to authenticate, in case of client authentication, is that possibly there are no credentials in the "well known" credential store (key chain). In order to implement some custom authentication approach where you setup the credentials yourself you MUST use `NSURLConnection` in asynchronous mode and implement the delegate methods. There might be other reasons, too.

What you should do now to accomplish this task, is

1. Use `NSURLConnection` in asynchronous mode - you are likely required to implement the delegate method `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:`.
2. Ensure that you setup the headers for the request correctly, e.g. it wouldn't hurt to set "Content-Type" header and possibly the "Accept" header.
3. Fix timeout (leave it at default).
4. Check errors correctly.
5. Check the response, that is status code and Content-Type if that is what you expect.
6. Process the response data.
7. Implement `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` according the given authentication challenge.